# appengine creating Queue failing

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Creating a task queue in appengine is failing with the following Exception

```
com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueApiHelper.translateError(QueueApiHelper.java:86)
com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueImpl.add(QueueImpl.java:505)
com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueImpl.add(QueueImpl.java:427)
com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueImpl.add(QueueImpl.java:412)
```

It is working fine in the local dev server for a while before it fails with the following exception

```
com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueApiHelper.translateError(QueueApiHelper.java:74)
com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueImpl.add(QueueImpl.java:505)
com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueImpl.add(QueueImpl.java:427)
com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueImpl.add(QueueImpl.java:412)
```

Here is the code I am using

```
TaskOptions taskOption = TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl(servletPath).countdownMillis(time)
taskOption.taskName(name)

Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue(taskQueue)
queue.add(taskOption)
```

Comment: There should be a line of text above the error line explaining the error more in details. Please post it.

Comment: Yeh, there should be but no ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that local server is more lax with the taskName. Exception at QueueApiHelper.java:86 will occur in appengine if the name has uppercase or if the name is being reused (Hopefully, appengine will allow the name to be reused after certain period. I have notice that it won't allow reusing the name with 5 minutes.) . Exception at QueueApiHelper.java:74 in local server will occur if two tasks with the same name is created at the same time. So here is the (descriptive)fix

```
taskOption.taskName(name.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z0-9]+","") + System.currentTimeMillis())
```